# Modifying global variables from gdb

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb, global-variables

Using GDB, I'm trying to modify a global variable.  The global variable is defined in a shared library - not sure if that makes any difference.  But I get an error "Cannot access member".  Here is what I am doing:

```
$ gdb /usr/lib/libmylib.so
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-56.el6)
...

(gdb) p GlobalVar1
$1 = 0

(gdb) info variable GlobalVar1
All variables matching regular expression "GlobalVar1":

File src/file.cc:
static volatile int GlobalVar1;

Non-debugging symbols:
0x00000000007d2f08  GlobalVar1
(gdb) 

(gdb) info address GlobalVar1
Symbol "GlobalVar1" is static storage at address 0x7d2f08.

(gdb) set var GlobalVar1=1
Cannot access memory at address 0x7d2f08
```

Any ideas why this is failing?

Comment: You ran gdb on the library itself.  Is the program running?  Writing to memory only works if there is an inferior running, or maybe if you did `set write on`.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  You are correct.  See my response to Vladimir below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are debugging without process.
 Just create some faked hello-world and link it to the forementioned library:

```
#g++  -ggdb hello.cc   -lmylib
#gdb ./a.out
#gdb> b main
#gdb> r
#gdb>p globalVar1
#gdb> set globalVar1
...
```

Comment: Vladimir, thanks!  This was my problem - I was starting gdb without a process.  I should have started gdb with --pid=<pid>.  I suppose I could have tried using a fake program as you suggested, but I already have a running program that uses the library.  So starting gdb against the process of the running program did the trick!  Thanks!